# Vectorizing numpy choices

Tags: python, numpy, random

Say I have the 2-dimensional numpy arrays `A`, `B` and `P` and they all have the same shape. `A` and `B` represent two choices and `P` contains probabilities in the interval [0,1]. Now I want to create a new array `C` where `C[i,j]` is given by `A[i,j]` with probability `P[i,j]` and by `B[i,j]` with probability `1-P[i,j]`.

Here in an example code for `A` filled with zeros, `B` filled with ones and random probabilities `P`:

```py
import numpy as np
rows = 4
columns = 5
A = np.zeros((rows, columns)) # all zeros
B = np.ones_like(A)           # all ones
P = np.random.rand(*A.shape)  # random numbers in interval [0,1)
C = np.array([[
    np.random.choice([A[nrow,ncol], B[nrow,ncol]], p=[P[nrow,ncol], 1-P[nrow,ncol]])
    for ncol in range(P.shape[1])]
    for nrow in range(P.shape[0])])
```

Does anybody know a way to do this without the for-loops? (For big arrays the for-loops limit performance immensely...)

Comment: Isn't all that functionally equivalent to `C = np.random.choice(2, size = (rows, columns))`?  Since `U(0, 1) > U(0, 1) = Beta(1, 1) = U(0, 1)`?  In general though, probability based on another probability like this is a Beta or Dirichlet distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Just get a random array `r = np.random.rand(*A.shape)` and do

```py
C = (r <= p) * A + (r > p) * B
```

and you are done. Stuff like this must be part of the standard library somewhere, though.

Comment: It is simpler to use `C = np.where(r <= p, A, B)`.

Comment: Look into `np.where`, which is the 2-element version, `np.select` for more than 2 elements, or `np.cumsum` and `np.argmax` for what I think is a less awkward solution.